# Error: permission_denied at /categories: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an assignment given by some recruiter and here I need to build an e-commerce site using react redux, and firebase.

The front end part is done but not able to get the data from firebase.
here is my rules Tab content how can I modify it.

```
this.props.firebase.categories().on('value', snapshot => {
        // Not coming here.
            console.log(snapshot, snapshot.val)
        }, (error) => {
        // Error shows here
            console.log(error);
        });


// Content of Rules tab
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Followed this tutorial:
https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/#react-application-setup

Answer (score 0):

Set read and write permissions to true in rules (firebase).